# how to do the for-loop for integrate() in R

Tags: r, for-loop, integrate

The following is my R-code, if i set the "c" equals to 10,11,12,13,14 separately,to get five different "final",how could I set the loop for integrate()function? Thanks you in advance.

```
a<-1;b<-2;c<-10
integrand<-function(k) 
{
  a+b*c*k
}
outcome<-integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = 1)
final<-outcome$value+c
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by using anonymous functions and `sapply`

```
# create a function with two parameters
aux_function<-function(k,c) 
{
  a+b*c*k
}
# integrate on x with different c values
outcome<-sapply(10:14, function(c) {integrate(function(x) {aux_function(x,c)}, lower = 0, upper = 1)$value +c})
```

### Edit

Onyambu found a better answer in the comments below

```
outcome<-sapply(10:14,  function(c) {integrate(aux_function,lower=0,upper=1,c=c)$value +c})
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `function(x)`? Also avoid giving names different from the name OP gave`sapply(10:14, function(c) integrate(integrand,lower=0,upper=1,c=c)$value+c)`

Comment: @Onyambu I have this error when I run your code `Error in f(x, ...) : unused argument (c = c) `

Comment: here `integrand` is exactly same as your `aux_function`. Not the one OP provided

Comment: oh ok, I get it now, you are right this is easier to read than my solution

Answer (score 2):

I guess my answer is right. May I post my own answer?

```
  h<- list()
  g<- numeric()
  a<-1;b<-2;c<-c(10,11,12,13,14)

  for(i in 1:length(c))
  {
    h[[i]] = function(k){ a+b*c[i]*k}
    g[i] = integrate(h[[i]], lower=0, upper=1)$value+c[i]
  }
  g
```

Comment: You may benefit from using `for(i in 1:length(c))` if you intend c to be different length vectors and don't want to have to update the loop each time.

Comment: Yes, you can answer your own question, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow).