# Evaluating an integral in R multiple times

Tags: r, numerical-integration, integral

I am trying to integrate the next function with respect x

```
integrand <- function(x) {
f1 <- pnorm((1/sqrt(u/x))*( sqrt((t*u*v)/x) - sqrt(x/(t*u*v)) ))}
```

where,

```
v=10
u=5
```

However, I need to integrate considering different values of t, so tried defining a sequence of values as:

```
t=seq(0,100,0.1)
```

And used the sapply function as:

```
data=sapply(t, function(x) integrate(integrand, lower = 0 , upper = 10000)$value )
```

I got these errors:

```
    Error in integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = 10000) : 
  evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In (t * u * v)/x : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In x/(t * u * v) : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In (1/sqrt(u/x)) * (sqrt((t * u * v)/x) - sqrt(x/(t * u * v))) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I haven't had any luck.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Regards!

Comment: For starters `u/x` when your `seq` starts at 0, will be undefined. Then you're assigning to `f1`, but your function isn't returning anything. Did you mean evaluate that function within the distribution function for a normal?

Comment: What is causing your error is that `t` is vector of length 1001. I believe you are trying to loop through all those values and assign it to `x` in your function. However, your function is also a function of `t`. So, it's trying to evaluate your function where `u`, `v`, and `x` all have single values and `t` has 1001, which is throwing an error.

Comment: Thank you for your help,  thank you for pointing out the two problems. I am trying to find a way to evaluate the integral with every value of  "t", lets say that evaluate the integral when t =0.1, then when t=0.2 and so on. Maybe the sapply function is no appropriate.

Comment: Then what values are you trying to evaluate `x` for?

Comment: I am considering the integral limits defined in the integrate function "lower = 0 , upper = 10000"

Comment: So you want to evaluate this for every `x` between 0 and 1000, and `t` between 0 and 100? That is a very large computation.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to evaluate 1000 integrals (for "t" from 0.1 to 100), every integral with respect "x" from 0 to 1000

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I think I have solved the situation, your insights have helped me. I considered a "for" loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `sapply` like so:

```
sapply(t, function(t) {
  integrate(function(x) {
    pnorm((1/sqrt(u/x))*( sqrt((t*u*v)/x) - sqrt(x/(t*u*v)) ))
  }, lower = 0, upper = 1000)$value
})
```

**Output**

```
[1]  0.000000  5.416577 10.251273 15.146418 20.084907 25.049283 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A previous post have a similar problem with an specific solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60161489/how-to-do-the-for-loop-for-integrate-in-r)

the code would result as:

```
t=seq(0,100,0.1)
fu<- list()
int<- numeric()
for(i in 1:length(t))
  {
    fu[[i]] = function(x){
    f1 <- pnorm((1/sqrt(u/x))*( sqrt((t[i]*u*v)/x) - sqrt(x/(t[i]*u*v)) ));
  }
    int[i] = integrate(h[[i]], lower=0, upper=1000)$value
  }
  int
```